# Iterate members of a bitfield

Tags: c++, bit-fields

We have this example:

```
struct X {
  int e0 : 6;
  int e1 : 6;
  int e2 : 6;
  ...
  int e10 : 6;
};

struct X c;
```

How can I access the members "automatically", something like that:
c.e{0-10} ?
Say if I want to read c.e0, then c.e1 ...
If my struct would have 1000 elements, I do not think that I should write so much code, right ?

Can you help me with a workaround, an idea ?
I mention that I already read other posts related somehow to this problem, but I did not find a solution.

Thank you very much !

Comment: What's the business case for using a struct here? Would any other data elements work as well?

Comment: Do you really need 6-bit int members? This will affect the answers to the question.

Comment: Note to introspection: C++ wishes it had you.

Comment: You aren't using a struct: you have a bitfield, which is something I never used in 10+ years of C and C++. Can you tell us why an array doesn't do the job ?

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you but if your `struct would have 1000 elements` than your design would be horribly broken...

Comment: My C instincts are telling me to try some evil macro trickery but I don't think it would work here. Might `struct bits { int e :6; }; struct X { bits e[10]; };` do the trick for you? It'll waste some space, but you'll get the same data in an easier-to-access format. The only other way I can think of is to write a program to read a template and automatically generate the $%@#load of lines of code to manually access each element individually.

Comment: The struct only has to be three values long, any more than four can use an array of these structs.

Comment: Thank you everybody for the answers ! It's a problem that should simulate SET Union and Intersection. The ideea is that I should use a struct like that. The biggest numbers that I should have in let's say e0 is 32. That's why I have bit fields of 6. What was not specified in the problem is how many elements a SET would have. Even if we have a SET A and another one, B with A having 5 elements and B having 3, it is still inconvenient(because I had to write some lines of code).

Comment: @ Chris Lutz, I have thought a workaround like the one you presented, but that solution it is not embodied in the requirements of the problem.

Comment: @C. Ross thanks, I think I can use that somehow!

Answer (score 5):

As others have said, you cannot do exactly what you want with bit fields. It looks like you want to store a large number of 6 bit integers with maximum space efficiency. I will not argue whether this is a good idea or not. Instead I will present an old-school C like way of doing exactly that, using C++ features for encapsulation (untested). The idea is that 4 6 bit integers require 24 bits, or 3 characters.

```
// In each group of 3 chars store 4 6 bit ints
const int nbr_elements = 1000;
struct X
{
    // 1,2,3 or 4 elements require 3 chars, 5,6,7,8 require 6 chars etc.
    char[ 3*((nbr_elements-1)/4) + 3 ] storage;
    int get( int idx );
};

int X::get( int idx )
{
    int dat;
    int offset = 3*(idx/4);      // eg idx=0,1,2,3 -> 0 idx=4,5,6,7 -> 3 etc.
    char a = storage[offset++];
    char b = storage[offset++];
    char c = storage[offset];
    switch( idx%4)  // bits lie like this; 00000011:11112222:22333333
    {
        case 0: dat = (a>>2)&0x3f;                    break;
        case 1: dat = ((a<<4)&0x30) + ((b>>4)&0x0f);  break;
        case 2: dat = ((b<<2)&0x3c) + ((c>>6)&0x03);  break;
        case 3: dat = c&0x3f;                         break;
    }   
    return dat;
}
```

I will leave the companion put() function as an exercise.

Comment: I would make it `template<std::size_t N> struct X { char[3*((N - 1) / 4) + 3] storage; };` to make the number of elements adjustable, but that may or may not be necessary. Also, I'd add a check to make sure the index is in range.

Comment: @bsabin You're welcome. If you would like me to write put() as well just ask in comments. I only just noticed that there is a similar answer to mine already and someone commented that the write (put) would be "hellish". I am sure it would not be too bad actually.

Comment: @Chris. Thanks for your suggestions, I am more of a C programmer as you might be able to tell, but I am trying to use more of C++ and I can learn from comments like yours.

Comment: @Bill - I generally prefer C over C++, but the more I get used to the (sometimes horrendous) syntax, the more I'm learning to appreciate (some) features of C++. I'm finding that the fusion of old-school C hacks and macros with C++ operator overloading is quite interesting, and can make for some nice new (and remarkably clear) syntax: http://phimuemue.com/blog.php?article=172 (not mine, but still awesome)

Comment: @Chris. That example is very cool, and great for personal projects where you can embrace such stuff and really integrate it into your mental model. But of course if you add something like that into a big project you potentially create a maintenance nightmare for the community. Linus Torvalds loves ranting about this aspect of C++, and his examples are a lot less hard core than your one. It's interesting, modern C++ features can create apparently really nice code that is great except for the side effect that any attempt to pull the code apart and understand it drowns in a million < and > chars.

Comment: Torvalds just prefers `x>>6 & 0x1F` over `x<6>` for reasons I can't fathom. With this kind of problem, performance and readability are fundamentally at odds.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like a struct isn't the right tool for what you're trying to do.  You need either an [array](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/c-arrays.html) or a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/).  Arrays are used for storing a number of the same type of data.  Vectors are array wrappers that manage the addition and removal of items automatically.

If you need a list of the same data, and some other data (say a string) you can make an array or a vector part of your struct.

```
struct X {
   int[10] numbs;
   string name;
};

X c;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. To do this would require some form of reflection, which is not supported in either C or C++.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

```
char getByte(char *startPos, int index) {

    int i = (index*6) / 8;

    if (index % 4 == 0)
        return 0b11111100 & startPos[i] >> 2;
    else if (index % 4 == 3)
        return 0b00111111 & startPos[i];
    else if (index % 4 == 2)
        return (0b00001111 & startPos[i] << 2) | (0b11000000 & startPos[i+1] >> 6);
    else
        return (0b00000011 & startPos[i] << 4) | (0b11110000 & startPos[i+1] >> 4);
}
```

Comment: Just curious - have you tested this? Read access seems doable this way, but write access would be hellish.

Comment: @Chris, no I didn't test it but I have done a lot of bit-twiddling in the past. I've changed it to something much easier to read though, setByte would be similar. I haven't tested this either though, so beware of the bugs!

Comment: This doesn't have defined behavior. It's permissible for the compiler to insert padding which is not accounted for here. (Though it should work for most cases)

Comment: @Billy - Can the compiler insert padding with bitfields? I would have thought that would defeat the point of bitfields.

Comment: @Billy, I thought that the idea of bitfields that you can read them directly from network buffers or file formats to save time messing about with this sort of thing. If they're not as-defined when struct packing is disabled, what use are they?

Comment: @Chris: As far as I am aware, yes. Bitfields can help reduce memory footprint, but AFAIK the compiler is not *required* to pack things in that many bits. I could be wrong though. (99% of compilers are going to be fine with it however)

Comment: What I mean is, the compiler is not allowed to change the width of the individual members, but it's allowed to insert padding between the members. (I.e. compilers can do this in general and I'm not aware of an exception just because a struct contains bitfields)

Comment: Pretty sure that should be `index % 4 == 3` and not `index % 3`

Comment: @Billy - Done some Googling and all the sources I've found agree with you. Rather unfortunate, but apparently true.

Comment: @Billy, @Chris, @Gaz: I'm pretty sure the underlying type of the bitfield plays a role in where packing is allowed or not.  e.g. if that's a 16-bit `int` in the question, the compiler is permitted to put 2 6-bit fields and 4 bits of padding in an `int`, but that wouldn't be permitted with a 32-bit `int`, the compiler would be obliged to put 5 6-bit fields together plus 2 bits of padding to make an `int`.

Comment: @Ben @Chris @Gaz: See 6.2.6.1 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf . It's unclear whether or not it is allowed. 6.7.2.1 Clause 10 indicates that if the bit field can fit into a single addressable unit (usually `char`) that the compiler must fit it into that single addressable unit, but that it may insert space between addressable units if the bit field is too wide to fit into a single unit.

Comment: Belive me, I can not use something like that on such problem. :-) Thank you very much for your support ! :D

Comment: @Ben, thanks, I'll change it. @Billy, interesting, thank you.

Comment: @Gaz: I think some bitshifts might also be in order.

Comment: @Ben, oops! My first solution had bitshifts but it was horrible (no if block). I'll add those! Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since your bitfields are of the same size, you could encapsulate `std::bitset` (or `vector<bool>`, gulp...) and provide your own iterators (each increment moving the bookmark six bits) and `operator[]` (etc) to allow your code to be more simple to write.

I am sure performance would suck compared to the bitfields though.